# Unable to open database with sqlite3 on cygwin

Tags: windows, sqlite, cygwin

I seem to be getting the error as shown below:

[image]

Am I missing out on something here and not giving cygwin the right to write to a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple answer to this question. You [cannot](http://ask-leo.com/why_cant_i_write_any_files_to_my_c_drive.html) write to the `C:` drive. Try moving into a different folder and that will allow you to write your `.sql` files.